# How to use 'whos' to return the Size only

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to return the 'Size' of all workspace variables. 'whos' returns more than only the 'Size'. But I don't need the other things. How can I return the 'Size' or 'Name' or 'Bytes' exclusively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`whos`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) with a output variable specified, you get a [structure](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) back, with the fields:

```
name
size
bytes
class
global
sparse
complex
nesting
persistent
```

If you do: `S = whos;`, you can see the results this way:

```
S.size
S.name
```

If you want to *store* those in a variable, you can do:

```
names = {S.name}
names = 
'A'    'B'    'str'
```

Or if the values are matrices of equal size, like for instance `size` for normal matrices, you can do:

```
sizes = [S.size];
```